# Combined dax to return average

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following measure :

```
Absenteeism = 
VAR OrgList = {
    "Attrition - BLR",
    "BLR - EY Domestic EYG",
    "BLR - EY Domestic EYG V2",
    "BLR - EY Domestic Res",
    "BLR - EY Domestic Res V2",
    "BLR – EY English Gold Platinum V2",
    "BLR - EY International EYG",
    "BLR - EY International EYG V2",
    "BLR - EY International Res",
    "BLR - EY International Res V2",
    "BLR - EY New Joiner",
    "BLR - EY OJT V2",
    "CSI - EY BLR",
    "CSI - EY BLR V2",
    "E-Services - EY BLR",
    "E-Services - EY BLR V2",
    "Etihad - BLR",
    "Etihad - BLR V2",
    "GSS - EY BLR",
    "GSS - EY BLR V2",
    "Quality - BLR V2",
    "SME - EY BLR V2",
    "WFM - EY BLR RTA",
    "WFM - EY BLR RTA V2",
    "1. Other Support - BLR V2"
}

VAR FilterTable =
    FILTER('ActivityHours_Raw', NOT('ActivityHours_Raw'[Organization] IN OrgList))

VAR Globalab =
    CALCULATE(
        IF(
            [Unplanned Leave] = 0,
            0,
            [Unplanned Leave] / ([Paid Hours] - [Planned Leave])
        ),
        FilterTable
    )
Return
Globalab
```

And another one here :

```
BLR Absent = 
VAR Leave_categories = {"Sick", "Absent Informed ", "Absent Not Informed", "Emergency Leave", "Unpaid Leave", "Sick Paid", "Absent Informed", "Sick Unpaid", "General Unavailability", "NCNS"}
VAR Leave_cal = CALCULATE(COUNT('BLR Attendance'[Attended ]), FILTER('BLR Attendance', 'BLR Attendance'[Attended ] IN Leave_categories || ('BLR Attendance'[Attended ] = "General Unavailability" && 'BLR Attendance'[Date] >= DATE(2023,6,1))))
VAR Agent_count = COUNT('BLR Attendance'[Name])
RETURN
    Leave_cal / Agent_count

If i combine Dax 2 (BLR Absent) to Dax 1 (Absenteesim), 

"Return
Globalab + BLR Absent"
```

In Matrix table it returns 13% insead of 6% which is average

Expecting return value should be around 6% :

[image]

Comment: Have you considered merging them in PowerQuery M  step instead of at the DAX level? It can get a bit more complicated with lambda statements, but a basic if condition on type could help you here

Comment: I tried merging them.. Both datasets are totally different and kinda independent in some ways. 

While i filter out on site level.. i get accurate value but when it comes to Matrix table.. The total adds Globalab and BLR absent.